# With the global flag I am unable to detect multiple occurrences of the word 'blue'?

Tags: javascript, regex

Through the following script I try to detect multiple occurrences of the word `blue` but it just prints `e` . Why is that ?

```
var reg_5 = /[blue]+/g;
var str = "Sky was dark and the mood was blue.Sky was dark but the water felt blue.";
document.write("<br / >" + reg_5.exec(str));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regexp is wrong, your search for the occurrence of either b,l,u or e appearing one or more times.

your regexp shoul be:

```
/blue/g
```

and then using a loop:

```
var finder = /blue/g;
var result;
while( ( result = finder.exec( str ) ) ){
    console.log( result );
}
```

you need execute the regexp as long the result becomes null. Without the g flag it would not work like this. The finder has a lastIndex property that indicates the index of the last match, so if you want to reuse the regexp without recreating it just set this property back to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the character class

`var reg_5 = /blue/g;`

Comment: This would still only find the first occurrence because he's using `.exec()` without a loop

Answer (score 0):

It prints `e` because the first match of `/[blue]+/g;` in `str` is the `e` in `the`. See phillip's answer for why that is and what the regex should be.

If you are matching globally, i.e. looking for more than one match, and you are not using capture groups `()`, you can just use `match` to get an array of all the matches.

```
var m = str.match( /blue/g );
var n = m == null ? 0 : m.length;

console.log( 'The word "blue" appeared ' + n + ' times.' );
```